# Javascript get file path of input file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file

how can I get the file path of the selected file

```html
<input type="file" class="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" (change)="onPreviewCoverSelected($event)">
```

I have to display the selected image before the form is validated but I need it's path...

Comment: You can't get path of the file from user's computer

Comment: Knowing the path to it wouldn't help you display it. Browsers block local URLs in `src` attributes in pages loaded over HTTP.